# In WebStorm, is there a way to automatically inject a language into an argument of a particular function?

Tags: webstorm

Here's what my code looks like.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} css
 * @param {string} [otherParam]
 */
const addStyle = (css, otherParam) => {
  // Do stuff...
};

addStyle('#element{font-weight:bold;}', 'Some string of text');
```

Here are the current manual and theoretical ways I know to accomplish this.

## 1. Manual Injection

This works great, but I'd like it to be automatic.

Step 1:

[image: Manual Injection Step 1]

Step 2:

[image: Manual Injection Step 2]

Result:

[image: Manual Injection Result]

## 2. Injection Comment

This won't work because it injects CSS into all arguments of the function.

[image: Injection Comment 1]

The only way to get it to work is by putting each argument on a separate line like this, but again I'd like it to be automatic without the need to insert the comment line each time. This is the method I currently use.

[image: Injection Comment 2]

## 3. Language Injection Settings

I tried messing around with this for a while, but I can't seem to figure it out.

[image: Language Injection Settings]

```
+ jsLiteralExpression().withSuperParent(2, jsLiteralExpression().withText(string().startsWith("addStyle(")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom Language Injection rule seems to work just fine here for your test code. Tested in a plain JavaScript file using PhpStorm 2020.1.2 on Windows 10:

[image]

The actual rule:

[image]

```
+ jsArgument(jsReferenceExpression().withQualifiedName("addStyle"), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That certainly gets me going in the right direction! It seems to work well for strings, but it doesn't work with concatenated strings. 
Example `addStyle('.bold{font-weight:bold;}' + '.underline{text-decoration:underline;}')`

Comment: Works in PHP context (but it uses different "injection functions" to decide where to inject). Must be specific to injection support (concatenations in particular) in JavaScript land (as PHP has more advanced handling -- e.g. SQL commands are quite often split into multiple concatenations etc). You will see the same behaviour in `new RegExp('^.*' + '$')`. Better report it as a bug/feature request to WebStorm devs (and post a ticket number back): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: It looks like it could be this one https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8233

Comment: Make a new ticket, provide your custom language injection rule and show both working and not working examples and let WebStorm devs to look into it. Maybe automatic language injections work differently to manual ones (via comment or pure manual via IDE GUI). **P.S.** I've also tried more simple `+ jsArgument("addStyle", 0)` pattern .. and it shows exactly the same behaviour.