# Can we hint custom JavaScript function parameter type as CSS selector in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a function

```
function all(cssSelector){
    return document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
}
```

If I call `all('#id')` the IDE didn't seem to know that the string is CSS selector but if I call `document.querySelectorAll` directly I can use autocomplete.

Is there any annotation that can fix this?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447284/783119 -- should work for your case as well: `+ jsArgument(jsReferenceExpression().withQualifiedName("all"), 0)`. NOTE: it's better be uniquely named function, otherwise it will be applied to ALL functions with such name which may not be desired.

Comment: Why does it need to know it's a CSS selector?

Comment: @cela so that we can use CSS autocomplete every time we invoke this function.

Comment: @thReality So did you managed to make it work for your code?

Comment: @LazyOne yeah, but IMO it kinda weird that there isn't an annotation for this. We have to do this on every pc that our devs use if they need it. and this setting overrides other functions too.

Comment: @thReality Then please complain to JetBrains developers on their Issue Tracker... and not me. P.S. AFAIK there is no such functionality (injected language specified in a parameter hints for a function declaration) for PHP or Python either (no idea about other IDEs/languages). PHP stuff (e.g. RegEx injection for `preg_...` functions) use the same injection mechanism in PhpStorm. JavaScript's standard stuff (`querySelectorAll()` etc) and jQuery is hardcoded in JS plugin though (similar stuff, just in plugin and you cannot see those rules in GUI).

Comment: @thReality https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29167 -- this is the ticket I was able to find so far.

Comment: `setInterval()`, `setTimeOut()`, `RegEx` constructor, `executeSql()`, even previously mentioned `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` (I was wrong about them apparently -- now they are "normal" injections) -- they ALL done via standard Language Injection mechanism and fully editable (you can clone them) in a GUI -- just go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections` and look at entries that start with `js` prefix.